# Image-fluid not scaling col size

Tags: bootstrap-4

I can't find a recent answer regarding the following issue: When I try to use a responsive image (with `class="img-fluid"`) it stretches an absurd height but keeps the correct width.

What I am trying:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
       <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3>
                   <small>Brand</small><br />
                   Product name
                </h3>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The issue effects on MacOS Safari and Chrome except firefox.

Comment: You have columns nested without the required row between. That may not be related, but I'd fix it. (I don't think that col-12 element does anything.)

Comment: Yea there are many uncessary codes, like `.col-12`, and `.row` that wraps the image. I removed them and added a container outside: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ndguc4ro/8/. Still not sure what you meant by the image stretching an absurd height.

Comment: I think you fixed the issue. 

I often use extra col-12's to create a margin / use an outside col for shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David answered, I was wrapping tomuch. Simply by removing col-12 fixed my issue.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>
                        <small>Brand</small><br />
                        Product name
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```